# If $A$ is a group ring then $A\otimes_{A^e}A$ has certain structure as A bimodule.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-topology

Let $A$ be the group ring of $\pi_1(X)$ for some topological space $X$. Let us assume the ring be field or any integral domain. Then $A$ has A-bimodule action(left and right multiplication respectively). $A^{e}=A\otimes_{k}A^{op}$ acts on the left of A which gives us the bimodule structure. Now the question is how would this algebra $A\otimes_{A^e}A$ look like? I believe it look like has generator as conjugacy classes.

We can just look at $a\otimes1=a\otimes_{A^e} b.b^{-1}=a\otimes_{A^e}(b\otimes_{k}b^{-1}.1)=b.a.b^{-1}\otimes_{A^e}1$.

But i'm not able to show if $b\otimes_{A^e}1=a\otimes_{A^e}1$ then $b$ and $a$ are conjugates.

Comment: Why is it important that it is the group ring of a fundamental group? Due to Eilenberg-MacLane spectra your group could be anything so this doesn't give you any new information!

Comment: yeah that is true...